# Microphone volume seems to increase via PulseAudio but arecord does not see any increase

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi-os, microphone, i2s, compute-module-4

I am still trying to understand how the audio input/output stuff works over PCM on the Pi its new to me as I've never dealt with it before. All of the testing below was on the latest Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit.

I got our microphone setup and working by following this tutorial.

[Adafruit Microphone](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test)

When I use the following line to record the audio everything functions and I can hear myself speaking in the recording but the volume is far too low.

```
arecord -D plughw:0 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v file.wav
```

So I went ahead and ran the following commands.

```
pacmd set-source-volume 0 600000
pacmd set-source-volume 1 600000
```

I did it twice as I wasn't quite sure which source device was the one I was looking for. Either way after running the second command in the upper right hand corner it listed the microphone volume at 916% which is perfect (I know its super loud I will reduce it but for the time being I am trying to find out how much of a boost we really need).

However when using the arecord command above the volume doesn't seem to change for the microphone.

Is this because arecord is part of alsa and that is now obsolete? If so what can I record with that will abide by the 916% volume that I set? Audacity didn't seem to work and parec didn't seem to work either so I'm a bit confused as to what is going on here.

Thanks for the help ahead of time!